# Vim как убрать знаки ~

Tags: linux, vim

В этом редакторе есть одна(на мой взгляд) плохая фича, все строки на которых нет текста помечены знаком `~` Можно ли их убрать?

Comment: Это не строки, на которых нет текста, а строки, которых вообще нет в файле. Строки, на которых нет текста (то есть имеется только перевод строки в первой позиции) так не помечаются.

Comment: Но вообще — да, можно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813059/is-it-possible-to-not-display-a-for-blank-lines-in-vim, только вот надо ли...

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, нет, **убрать** нельзя (о чём и написано по приведённой вами ссылке). не внося измнений в код программы *vim*, разумеется. но можно «покрасить» в цвет фона (о чём и написано по приведённой вами ссылке).